# Do native screensavers have a hidden configuration to show image file name/path?

Tags: screensaver, customization

I have an archive of images.  When they're displayed as a screensaver rotation, I'd like their names (and maybe the paths they're organized under) to show as an overlay to the image.

I don't really want to run a script that 'watermarks' the name or path permanently on the image.

I'd also think it's worthwhile to hear about 3rd-party screensavers that do this — though I think in that case it should be limited to one answer that gets edited by everyone (and eventually becomes a community-answer).  It'll change over time and need constant revision.

I'm on Mojave, but anything available for an in-support OS is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Photo Screensaver for Your Mac (ArtSaver)](http://www.cs.uni-bremen.de/~zach/software/ArtSaver/index.html).

The screensaver provides a plethora of options including name and path:

[image]